# Optimal way to handle array indexing in parallel?

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have the following situation:  I have a list of particles in a box of size L, where L is the length of one of the sides.

Next, I split the box into cells, where L/cell_dim = 7.  So there are 7*7*7 cells.

Finally, I read through all the particles, note their position, and calculate which cell they are in.

---

I accomplish the above in an openMP parallel for loop.  However, I need to capture the information in a thread safe fashion such that I don't have to loop through all the particles for each cell. So I need some way to record an arbitrary subset of the particles into each cell, in parallel.

---

The method I have right now makes use of the OpenMP critical code block.  I have an array size [7][7][7][max_particles], where max_particles is the highest number of particles per cell, but which is much less than the total number of particles. I record the index of the last particle added in a counter array size [7][7][7], and update the cell array according to the latest count in my parallel loop:

```
int cube[7][7][7][10];
int cube_counts[7][7][7]={0};

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(a lot)  
for (int i = 0; i < num_particles; i++){
    cell_x = //cell calculation;
    cell_y = //ditto;
    cell_z = //...;

#pragma omp critical
    {
        cube_counts[cell_x][cell_y][cell_z] += 1;

        // for readability 
        int index = cube_counts[cell_x][cell_y][cell_z];

        cube[cell_x][cell_y][cell_z][index] = i;
    }
}

// rest in pseudo code: 

foreach cell: 
    adjacent_cell = cell2

    particle_countA = cube_counts[cellx][celly][cellz]
    particle_countB = cube_counts[cell2x][cell2y][cell2z]

   // these two for loops will cover ~2-4 particles,
   // so super small...as a result of the cell analysis above. 
    for particle in cell:
        for particle in cell2: 
             ...do stuff
```

Although this works, it increases in speed by a factor of more than 2 when I am able to eliminate the critical block (I am on an intel coprocessor with 60 physical, 240 logical).

How would I accomplish this without need for the critical block?  I thought of doing a big array...but then I lose everything I gained when I iterate through the 7*7*7*257 (where 257 is the particle count) array.  Linked lists still have the race conditions.

Maybe some kind of unordered, thread safe list...?

Comment: Can't you just split the particles into N arbitrary roughly equal size sets where N is the number of physical threads?

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf I don't think so...maybe: the particles themselves are not thread safe--they interact with all the others.  So really, I just need to know which particles are in each cell...and how many there are. 

I think I could split them...then I would have 60*7*7*7 linked lists that I would have to stack together into 7*7*7 linked lists...it could get pretty nasty...and wind up having a similar number of critical operations...

Comment: In open mp the critical block is a pretty heavy construct, cause it locks a whole codefragment. A lock might work pretty well.

Comment: @Mehno wow thanks man!!..did not know about lock; def leaving this up, because I think there might be alternative ways to solve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a lock instead of the critical section can be driven further:

You may use atomic increment and atomic assignment pseudo calls ("intrinsics") that the compiler will translate to the correct x86 specific assembler instructions. This is however platform or even compiler dependent.

If your use a modern c++ compiler (C++11) then std::atomic_* might be the best way to do it.